# SQL / MySQL recursively pull from the same table

Tags: mysql, sql, recursion, logic

This problem is a strange one and I think I am simply just thinking about this wrong.  I am trying to get (recursively) all page URL's associated with a given contractor.  The three relevant tables are:

```
|-------------------------------------------------|
|                 client_sections                 |
|-------------------------------------------------|
|    contractor_id    |    reusable_section_id    |
|-------------------------------------------------|

|--------------------------------------------------------|
|                     reusable_sections                  |
|--------------------------------------------------------|
|    reusable_category_id    |    reusable_section_id    |
|--------------------------------------------------------|

|--------------------------------------------|
|             reusable_content               |
|--------------------------------------------|
|    reusable_section_id    |    page_url    |
|--------------------------------------------|
```

Now here is the need --  The first query is

```
SELECT reusable_section_id FROM client_sections where contractor_id = '119'
```

This gets all the **top level** "parent sections" --  Which is `reusable_category_id` in the table `reusable_sections`.  If I had to stop there I would have it handled.  But the caveat that I am running into is that each of those returned sections "could" be a **parent** section as well.  I have tried a nested `SELECT` and the result was nothing short of disastrous!

**What I am attempting:**

```
» Get contractor parent sections by contractor ID from client_sections table

    » get sections by reusable_category_id = reusable_section_id in reusable_sections  -- 

        » get page_url for all the sections returned (including the initial parents) 
          by reusable_section_id in reusable_content  -- I am good until this point

            » recur the last two steps with the current reusable_section_id as 
              reusable_category_id to check for children  (!!#$@#!!!)

                » Finally return all pages for all sections under that contractor_id
```

I have attempted queries ranging from crazy `JOINS`s to nested `SELECT`s to no avail.  I have read many posts including [This One](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41673677/recursive-query-from-the-same-table).  I am a competent SQL developer, I think my logic is flawed and a simple point in the right direction may just spark my creativity!  Is the best way a `WHILE` loop?  Nested `SELECT`? `JOIN`?  My brain is fried!  Help?

Comment: How many levels of recursion do you expect? If you don't have a limit, you cannot solve this problem simply by doing left outer joins. You will need a stored procedure, or you will have to implement it using a programming language. It is basically a tree.

Comment: Theoretically it could be infinite .. That's why the recursion has me stumped .. I could just do it with JOINS otherwise ..

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10646833/using-mysql-query-to-traverse-rows-to-make-a-recursive-tree :D .
See this: https://www.slideshare.net/billkarwin/models-for-hierarchical-data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have seems like a tree. If you are talking about navigating through a finite number of levels, than a finite number of left outer joins will be enough.

However, if you have an infinite number of possible levels, I do not think you can solve your problem using plain old SQL and joins.

You will have to resort to a stored procedure, or a programming language (php, java, etc).

However, it seems that people have implemented stored procedures on how to traverse through a tree, so you can go through that approach. 
Example:

[Using MySQL query to traverse rows to make a recursive tree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10646833/using-mysql-query-to-traverse-rows-to-make-a-recursive-tree)

Comment: Stored procedure was the trick ... That was a great read .. Thanks!